# Prevent VMWare Workstation from making computer lag when saving a snapshot

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

On VMWare Workstation 15.5.7 on Windows 10, when it saves a snapshot according to the periodic schedule, my whole computer slows down and the mouse lags. The computer is basically unusable until it finishes saving the snapshot. Is there a way I can limit the resources VMWare uses when saving a snapshot?

Comment: Enabling background snapshots probably should better distribute the load on your host machine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to reconfigure VMWare when taking snapshots. In order to resolve your issue you can try increasing the RAM of your host machine. If you want more details you can go to [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/430138/why-vm-snapshots-are-affecting-performance)

Answer (score 1):

Note: I think this is an AMD-specific issue.

Solution:
Power off VM and edit the vmx configuration file of your VM with a text editor or grep to include the parameters mainMem.ioBlockPages set to 2048 and mainMem.ioWait set to 1, reload the VM and power on.

Example:

```
mainMem.ioBlockPages = "2048" 
mainMem.iowait = "0"
```

via CLI:

```
cat test.vmx | grep -i mainMem 
mainMem.ioBlockPages = "2048" 
mainMem.iowait = "0"
```

You can play with the values a bit (although I'd use a base of 2 such as 4096 for the value of mainMem.ioBlockPages). We are essentially increasing the ioBlockPages and decreasing the ioWait values. Doing so we cut down on both the number of iterations and waiting time ( which in turn will decrease the total time to dump the memory to disk).

Workaround:
If you are waiting 20+ minutes for a snapshot to save before you can power off the VM to apply the fix above, you can speed up the snapshot process by simply pausing the VM while the snapshot is saving.  From there you can resume the VM and the snapshot will be completely saved.

Details:

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VMWare-Workstation-Slows-Down-When-Saving-State/td-p/2303945

KB:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/76687